# use arithmetic find conditions on cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

i need to convert following mysql condition to Cakephp find condition.

```
select * from bookings where (check_out_date - check_in_date) <=600 ;
```

Please help me.

Comment: see my edited answer it will defiantly work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Booking->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '(Booking.check_out_date - Booking.check_in_date) <=' => 600
    )
));
```

Answer (score -1):

try following code and debug it.

```
$bookings = $this->Booking->find('all',array
(
    'conditions' => array
    (
        '(Booking.check_out_date - Booking.check_in_date) <=' => 600
    ),
    'fields' => array
    (
        'Booking.*'
    ),
    'recursive' => -1
));
```

above code is tested and work like a charm.

Comment: I don't think you could format that code any worse than it currently is.

Comment: @dogmatic69 can u please tell me what is wrong with code? and explain downvote.!!